# Get selected dataGridView column data?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, get

C# Windows Form

I have a button that removes the selected row from the dataGridView. 
I also want the button to retrieve the selected rows "ordre" column value, so I can use it in a query that deletes the order from the sql table.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    //SQL connection
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt + "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
                    SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();

                    //SQL QUERY
                    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM bestillinger WHERE ordrenr = @ordre";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordre",dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ordre"].Value.ToString())

                    con.Open();
                    var ordre = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    con.Close();
```

But it doesn't work! No record was deleted

Answer (score 0):

After delete the row you can not get the value. So change your code like this

```
 //SQL connection
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + globalvariables.hosttxt 
+ "," + globalvariables.porttxt + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ha;Persist Security
Info=false; UID='" + globalvariables.user + "' ; PWD='" + globalvariables.psw + "'");
SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();

//SQL QUERY
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM bestillinger WHERE ordrenr = @ordre";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordre",dataGridView1.
SelectedRows[0].Cells["ordre"].Value.ToString())

con.Open();
var ordre = command.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong logic.

Since the row has been removed by RemoveAt(),

you cannot get a wrong row from dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.

```
  private void grdform1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
         {  
         If(e.ColumnIndex==0 ||e.ColumnIndex==1)
          {
           txtshowcolunm.text=e.ColumnIndex;
              }
            else
            {
          txtshowcolunm.text=e.ColumnIndex;
        }
           }
```